# Warning: something's wrong when ref $body->param->{aa}

Tags: perl

I'm testing `HTTP::Body`,

then

```
my $body = HTTP::Body->new($ct, $cl);
#..
use Data::Dumper;
warn Dumper($body);                  #A
warn ref $body;                      #B
warn Dumper($body->param);           #C
warn ref $body->param;               #D
warn Dumper($body->param->{aa});     #E
warn ref $body->param->{aa};         #F
```

OUTPUT:

```
#A
$VAR1 = bless( {
                 'param_order' => [
                                    'aa',
                                    'bb'
                                  ],
                 'param' => {
                              'aa' => 'b',
                              'bb' => 'a',
                            },
                 'cleanup' => 1
               }, 'HTTP::Body::MultiPart' );
#B
HTTP::Body::MultiPart at
#C
$VAR1 = {
          'aa' => 'b',
          'bb' => 'a',
        };
#D
HASH at 
#E
$VAR1 = 'b';
#F
Warning: something's wrong at
```

Why `Warning: something's wrong`, `$body->param->{aa}` is not a STRING? how to make it a STRING?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`something's wrong` is the default message that the `warn` function outputs when it receives an empty string or no input.

```
$ perl -e warn
Warning: something's wrong at -e line 1.

$ perl -e 'warn ""'
Warning: something's wrong at -e line 1.

$ perl -e '$body={param=>{aa=>"b"}};warn ref($body->{param}{aa})'
Warning: something's wrong at -e line 1.
```

I think you are also confused about what `ref` does on a normal scalar, such as a string. If the input to `ref` is not a reference, then the output is the empty string.

```
print ref(42);                 # no output
print ref(undef);              # no output
$foo="abc"; print ref($foo);   # no output
warn ref($foo);                # like warn "", so "something's wrong"
```

Comment: As opposed to what? Perl is not strongly typed so it will treat strings as numbers and numbers as strings depending on the context. With `ref` you can rule out whether it is a reference. With `Scalar::Util::looks_like_number` you can see if it is something that can be used without warning in numeric context. You can use something like `Devel::Peek` or `B` to look at the internals and tell whether Perl is storing the value as a number or a string at the current instant, but the joy of Perl is that the internal representation is something that the programmer rarely has to worry about.